# PreCompile header in Vistual studio 2005 problem

Tags: visual-c++

I have 2 projects. Both have the setting for Create/Use Precompiled Header set to "Use Precompiled Header (/Yu)"

I deleted a file in both projects. One compiles successfully but the other generates an error

```
Error   2   fatal error C1083: Cannot open precompiled header file: 'file.pch': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Rebuild"? An ordinary Build sometimes gets messed up. Also, is it really file.pch?

Comment: yes i have tried Rebuild ,i have set "Create/Use Precompiled" to "Not use PreCompile header" it will work but i want to know why this will not work when i use "Use Precompiled Header (/Yu)" and delete the PCH file from debug . as the other project is working of the deletion of pch file as well as the setting is set to "Use Precompiled Header (/Yu)".